# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException after migrating from Retrofit to Retrofit 2

Tags: ssl, retrofit, retrofit2, boringssl

I'm about to migrate from retrofit 1.9 to the latest version and encounter an issue...

My setup:

- Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (Android 7)
- Retrofit 2.3
- OkHttp 3.8

After migration I encounter this problem all of a sudden:

```
Read error: ssl=0x76f48af800: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error 
error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:641 0x76f480e0e0:0x00000001)
error:100000d7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:428 0x7718cd42d7:0x00000000))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to remove a leading '/' character in the REST interface definition path.

So combined, the base URL and service URL would have consecutive '/' characters which caused this error.